# polynomial time approximation algorithm problem

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, np-hard, approximation, polynomial-time-reductions

How can we actually define a polynomial-time 4-approximation algorithm for vertex cover or knapsack problem?

For say we have 2 approximation problems which less than equal 2C*. But when we have a larger or 4 approximation sizes how we can derive it.

Answer (score 1):

For vertex cover: start with an empty vertex cover $S$. Iteratively consider the edges of the graph. For each edge $e=(u,v)$, check if $\{u,v\} \cap S = \emptyset$. If that's the case we say that $e$ is **special** and we add both $u$ and $v$ to $S$.

At the end of the algorithm $S$ is a vertex cover containing at most twice as many vertices as a minimum vertex cover. To see that that's the case notice that special edges form a matching, that $|S|$ is twice the number of special edges, and that all vertex covers must contain at least one endpoint of each special edge.

Comment: well, then what does 4 approximation actually do? its not optimal one right. but whats the purpose of using 4 approximation algorithm>?

Comment: Whats the purpose of using a 4-approximation algorithm? I don't know... especially for vertex cover where a $2$-apx can be found in linear time. Maybe you can find some clues where you encountered this task. In general an algorithm with a higher approximation ratio might be more desirable, e.g., if it's faster than another approximation algorithm with a smaller approximation ratio.

Comment: I found this in a research article and they used 4 approximation algorithm ideas, but I am not sure how this operation works for string transformation.